# Socket Pending() method is not consistent when remote is ON

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

We have web application , it works as Socket Listner. I wanted to check before the AcceptSocket , whether there is any Client Socket available to connect to this listener. I want to display a message if there is no Client Socket to connect and cancel send/receive of data.

For this issue I  used  Pending Method of TcpListener class, but this works for me partly.

It works well if remote is not available, it return false. But when remote is available then sometimes Pending () method returns false. I want it to return true when remote is available all the time.

This is my code:
    public bool Communicationcation()
    {

```
    string strSiteID = "SiteID";
    socket.Start();

   if(!socket.Pending())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, no connection requests have arrived");
        return false;

    }
    else
    {
        client = socket.AcceptSocket();


        if (client.Connected == true)
        {
            // int nSiteID =  int.Parse(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("SiteID"));
            object dSiteID = GetSiteSetting(ref strSiteID);
            IPEndPoint clientep = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
            WriteLog(string.Format("Connected with {0} at port {1}", clientep.Address, clientep.Port));
            string strWelcome = STARTMESSAGE + "WHOAMI" + "     " + dSiteID + " " + dSiteID + FINISHMESSAGE;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strWelcome);
            int i = client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            WriteLog(String.Format("Message sent {0} bytes!", i));
            //Get reply from the Connected cleint.
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            i = client.Receive(bytes, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            if (i != -1)
            {
                WriteLog(string.Format(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

TcpListener class Pending method always returns false though Remote is running. If we run the code without debug.but when we debug the code then Pending method is inconsistent and returns some time false and some time true.

Comment: This code doesn't make a lot of sense. I don't know why you are returning false if a just-activated socket doesn't have a connection request pending; or why you are calling `AcceptSocket()` twice; and testing whether a just-accepted client is connected is futile.

Comment: @EJP

If Socket.Pending() method retuns false then I captured this value on page load to display client is  available or not. For this reason it returns false or true.

client.Accetpt() this method  typed twice by mistake here. in code I called only once.

I want to know there is client available or not.So how do I check this ?

Comment: But why are you calling Socket.Start() here, in this method? You're only allowing a tiny window for the client to connect.

Comment: @EJP I think we are not able to clearly explain problem, let me try little more explanation.You might be knowing that socket is a object of TCPListner Class.

socket.start() method is used to start listening incoming connection  for remote or client.

I could not get any other way to write code without doing a start, checking for some-one is waiting for connection. My basic issue is, if there is no-one to listen the code needs to tell user so and proceed for further work.